# Detecting only changes in control height

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to detect when only the height of a control is changed without using variables to save the previous control height?  I have code that I want to execute only when the height of a control is changed but the SizeChanged event is fired even when the width is changed.

Comment: What do you not like about caching the old height value?

Comment: Like using a variable to store the previous height?

Answer (score 1):

> without using variables to save the previous control height?

you can use a single variable, just use a dictionary. Try this exampe:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Dictionary<Control, int> heights = new Dictionary<Control, int>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (Control control in Controls)
        {
            heights.Add(control, control.Height);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (Control) sender;
        var oldHeight = heights[control];
        if (control.Height != oldHeight)
        {
            heights[control] = control.Height;

            // handle your resize
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the solution, I would recommend to store just control name instead of adding `Control` to the dictionary  `heights.Add(control.Name, control.Height);`

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  I was in the process of coding something very similar using a Dictionary.  I guess there is no way around using a variable

Comment: @H.Tran  Is there any specific reason why you don't want to use a variable or collection?

Comment: @Kurubaran Could you please provide an example of issue with my approach?

Comment: @Kurubaran No reason..just wanted to see if there was a cleaner option